# Hash Sum mismatch during Debian 9 installation in UEFI system

Tags: debian, linux-kernel

I am spending hard times to install `Debian 9` on the newly bought `Lenovo Thinkpad E560-A`. The `Secure Boot` options are all off in the UEFI Bios settings (as far as I know, at least) and Debian starts installing until it reaches to the point of failure. What the installer displays at this popint is:

```
Unable to install the selected Kernel
An error was returned while trying to install the Kernel into the target system
Kernel package: 'linux-image-amd64'.
check /var/log/syslog or see virtual console 4 for the details.
```

By viewing the `tty4` contents, I discovered that there is a `Hash Sum mismatch` and the expected `SHA256` is different from what it finds `in-target`.
I have no idea why it happens al the time and would like to ask you how to  solve the issue and make the installer continue its work until completed successfully. 
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Please show content of `/var/log/syslog` or `tty4`.

Comment: Those are really annoying errors and I've never heard of a good fix for them. Usually the problem is serverside. What mirror did you choose? Try another. I don't know if it is possible to change the mirror during the installation, but if possible, that's what I'd do. The most obvious way to attempt this is to simply return to the menu and select the option where you choose the mirror.

Comment: @richard : Because I didn't know how to send it in text format, here is the link to a picture I've taken => https://ibb.co/cugQKk

Comment: @richard: should'nt I enter my own Debian's key into UEFI BIOS? If so, How could I do it sir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at documentations over the internet about what `hash` is, and because I didn't have the hash to my `Debian-DVD`, I downloaded a fresh `Debian-9.1-DVD.iso` and checked its hash by executing `sha512sum debian-9-dvd.iso` and compared it to the hash given by `debian.org`.
Since they matched, I started installing this copy of debian, and it is working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

The image is out of focus, and the top is missing. I don't see any evidence relating to UEFI/Bios etc. Looks like a problem authenticating the packages to be installed. It is asking you to do an `apt-get update` this often fixes errors like this, if not then changing the mirror (the file server that you are getting the packages from), should do it.

I don't remember how to do this while installing, and it may depend on install method. If you can't get it to work as explained above. Then do an install, selecting the option to not update from the network (i.e. just install what is on the CD), and then when you have a working system, do `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade` (choose the enable sudo option as well).